# Generic class with dynamic number of types

Tags: c#, generics

I don't know how to phrase this question without using an example, so here we go...

I have defined a class like this:

```
public class Orchestration<T1, T2, T3>
{
```

With this constructor:

```
public Orchestration(Action<T1, T2, T3> action, int maxNumberOfRetries)
```

And a method called Run:

```
public bool Run(T1 one, T2 two, T3 three)
```

Now, if I do this:

```
var orchestration = new Orchestration<string, string, bool>(File.Copy, 5);
orchestration.Run("c:\filename.txt", "d:\filename.txt", true)
```

then the orchestration will try to run File.Copy 5 times before it return false, meaning the job has failed (the background here is that I was trying to rescue som files from a disk that only worked now and then)

The Orchestration class is generic and I can use it to run any method that has three parameters.

**My question is this:** Can I define the Orchestration-class in a manner that the number of parameters does not need to be determined in advance?

My goal then would be to enable it to run any method, not only methods that takes three parameters...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just have it accept an `Action` and close over whatever parameters you would have for your actual method:

```
public Orchestration(Action action, int maxNumberOfRetries)
```

---

```
var orchestration = new Orchestration(
    () => File.Copy("c:\filename.txt", "d:\filename.txt", true), 5);
```

It means knowing the parameter values on construction, rather than when calling `Run`, but in this context that doesn't seem like it should be a problem you can't resolve.

Comment: This works great if you're always calling it in the same context as it's created

Comment: You could make this more flexible by adding an `object[] parameters` param (i.e.`Action<object[]>`) or use `dynamic[]` to remove casting code

Comment: @TimS. That would be one possibility, if it's truly important to specify the parameters a while after specifying the method to be called (which I don't think is actually important here), but that loses pretty much all static type checking, so it's something that I would avoid doing unless it was strictly necessary.

Answer (score 10):

There is not a way to do this with generics in C#.  This would require something similar to [variadic templates in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), but there is no equivelent in the managed world.  That's why classes such as [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) have so many different classes with the factory methods to create the various versions.

If your parameters were either non-generic (ie: `object`) or always string, you could use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) to allow a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that.

Take a look at `Tuple`s, `Action`s and `Func`s in the .NET API... they have to create a version of each of those generic classes that takes 1 type arguments, one that takes 2 type arguments, etc. etc.

If you want something cool, try this:

```
static class Extensions {

  public static TimesDo( this int x, Action action) {
      for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) action.Invoke();   
  }
}
```

Then:

```
int x = 4; x.TimesDo(() => { File.Copy( .... ) } );
```

or

```
(5).TimesDo(() => { File.Copy( .... ) });
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for this method to be an extension on `int`.  Conceptually it is an operation that you perform on a delegate, not an integer, although since that would preclude the use of lambdas that avoid inferring the delegate instantiation, the best solution really is just to have a non-extension static method.

Comment: @Servy Why not?  It depends on your semantics.  If what is important is trying a variable number of times (i.e. you are always re-trying the same actions), then I would extend actions with a Retry method that takes an int.  If you are often retrying the same number of times, but with different actions, make it an extension method on int.  If both are equally important, then yeah, I'd agree with you, make it a simple static function.  Or, you could provide all three (with the extension methods calling the static method) and let the developer decide how to best express himself.

Comment: ints don't do operations a number of times, operations are executed a number of times.  You are inverting the parameter and the type conceptually performing that operation.  This is confusing to the reader, results in a less discoverable method, and also pollutes the method list of `int` with operations that are not applicable in the vast majority of concepts.

Comment: Says who?  Ruby has constructs like this, as do other languages.  Don't mistake style or idiom for conceptual necessity.